# Changing links in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have variable (loaded via AJAX) that contains a  piece of HTML document (but not the whole document with html, head and body.

I would like to change it this way:

> For each links in this variable that points to the same domain add
>   class internal_link.

For filtering links in the whole document I use for example:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
        return this.hostname && this.hostname === location.hostname;
    }).addClass('internal_link');
```

And it works without any problems. But I don't know how to use this code not on the whole document but on variable to change its value that way.

I tried below code:

```
html = data.content;

alert(html);

$(html).find('a').filter(function() {
    return this.hostname && this.hostname === location.hostname;
}).addClass('internal_link');

alert (html);
```

But it seems it doesn't work. internal_link class isn't in html when I run second alert.

How can it be done?

Sample page script:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $().ready(function() {

        html = '<a href="http://localhost">test</a>';

       alert(html);

        $(html).find('a').filter(function() {
            return this.hostname && this.hostname === location.hostname;
        }).addClass('internal_link');

        alert (html);


    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what does `data.content` look like? Are the anchors root elements etc ?

Comment: I've added simple test script to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the anchor is a root element, `find()` only finds children.

```
html = '<a href="http://localhost">test</a>';
```

so `$(html).find('a')` wouldn't work as the anchor is not a child.

You could use `filter()` instead, but that would ***only*** get root elements, and if you have both root elements and children if would fail,

Try it like this

```
var div = $('<div />').html(html); 

div.find('a').filter(function() {
    return this.hostname && this.hostname === location.hostname;
}).addClass('internal_link');
```

that creates a new parent element, so you're sure that any anchor in `html` will be a child once the content is appended to the container element.

Answer (score -1):

Your $(html) is not an object in the html-markup. Make sure the code your looking for is a part of the markup.

Use the following setup will work:

```
$('html').find('a').filter(function() {
    return this.hostname && this.hostname === location.hostname;
}).addClass('internal_link');
```

Beside you can fire the complete function on document ready to make sure your markup is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html').find('a').filter(function() {
        return this.hostname && this.hostname === location.hostname;
    }).addClass('internal_link');
});
```